# How to get checked value of Kartik radioList in javascript

Tags: javascript, forms, yii2, kartik-v

I would like to know how to get checked value in javascript. Here is my _form.php

```
        <?= $form->field($model, 'rdo')->radioList(["0"=>"Free","1"=>"Paid"], ['id' => 'rdo'])->label('Select Contribution') ?>
        <input type="text" id="name" name="name">
```

This is javascript code.

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#rdo").click(function(){
            $(":text").hide();
        });
            $("#rdo1").click(function(){
            $(":text").show();});
    });
```

I would like to appear text box when user choose free radio button and also text box will disappear when user choose paid radio. Thank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the value of current checked option by doing this:

```
$('#rdo input:checked').val();

// Or using name property
$('input[name="YourModelName[rdo]"]:checked').val();
```

Undefined is returned if nothing is selected.

So you should be able to do something like this:

```
$('input[name="YourModelName[rdo]"]').change(function () {
    if($('input[name="YourModelName[rdo]"]:checked').val() == 0) {
        // Do something
    }
    else if(.....){
        // Do something else
    }
});
```